# Error with insert in sqlite when using a string with --

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor, nuxt3

I am having issues when I try to run this query

```
"INSERT INTO rotables (rotable_id, codigo, uuid) VALUES (21126, 'T--SOMEOTHERTEXT', '6ad5ef19-829f-4e8c-8a26-8ff2b66f2100');"
```

so the problem here is that sqlite take all the strings after "--" characters like comments so it is like I am trying to insert like this

```
"INSERT INTO rotables (rotable_id, codigo, uuid) VALUES (21126, 'T"
```

Tech stack:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/ionic": "^0.12.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.3",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/sqlite": "^5.2.5",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.4.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vue-sqlite-hook": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/CrrIK1q3

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link because I didn't know how to test. However, I was able to find out that the issue is related when I use db.execute instead of db.query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved when I use db.query instead of db.execute like this

```
const query = "INSERT INTO rotables (rotable_id, codigo, uuid) VALUES (21126, 'T--SOMEOTHERTEXT', '6ad5ef19-829f-4e8c-8a26-8ff2b66f2100');";
//db is instance of SQLiteDBConnection
db.query(query);
```